# Access Web Services on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing

What are the ways of accessing web services on a BlackBerry device?

I've learned about XML for webservices.  We use SAX and DOM parsers in Blackberry. Are there any more ideas like this?

I also want to know what KSOAP is and how to use it on BlackBerry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, kSOAP is a library that lets you post soap requests to your web service. If the service accepts a simple POST request, the easiest way would be to use `HttpConnection`. [Here's](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=884) a good tutorial

I've also used [kXML2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/) for XML parsing, and that has worked out well for me till now.

Additionally, including 3rd party libraries is a pain (kSOAP and kXML), so [here's](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/155972-blackberry-ksoap2-tutorial.html) a guide that will hopefully save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/wsclient/java-android-blackberry/ which supports soap code generation for blackberry with additional library that manages everything, it generates native typed soap client and calling them is very easy. Otherwise you will be spending lot of time in xml to your types and types to xml conversions and so on. Plus date and many things are little complex to handle.